# fiddler not working with different modem

Tags: fiddler

For the sake of being very precise, I used fiddler to debugg my own web apps for mobile while using Motorola sb5101 cable modem. Worked like a charm.
I switched to a newer modem (thomson twg850), and it works all the same now. It's able to
capture traffic from the pc browsing, but it no longer captures traffic
from the mobile which is connected as usual via local wifi (same network as the computer of course).

Any thoughts? Any possible settings I might want to enable/disable on the other modem? I tried many possible settings despite the modems default ones, but could not get it to work as usual. It doesn't capture anything on mobile.

Before the local address of the computer was something
starting with 10.16....
Now it is 
192.168.0.10, and this is the ip that the mobile device proxies to

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is usually an option that (dis)allows Wifi based participants in the network to communicate among each other. This option often also affected the communication from Wifi to a LAN connected computer.

Therefore you should check configuration interface of your router if there is such an option.

Comment: Hello Robert,
Any indication on what might this Option be called? I can't seem to notice anything you mentioned 
Thanks alot